# Unable to import python functions within my Unit test folder

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest, python-3.8

My project structure looks like:

[image]

I now want to add some UTs within the test folder and specifically in UT_data_handler.py. Withing this UT file, I am trying to import the functions I want to test like:

```
from binary.data_handler import extract_data_file, convert_all_data_to_dict
```

Afterwards I get the following error:

```
> python UT_data_handler.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "UT_data_handler.py", line 3, in <module>
    from binary.data_handler import extract_data_file, convert_all_data_to_dict
ImportError: No module named binary.data_handler
```

Can someone provide a suggestion/solution?

Comment: Python does not recognize folders outside the scope of where the file was run. You will need to have a file outside of test and data, which will access test to run the tests.

Comment: That is why I added __init__.py files in all the folders of my project. What do you mean by "You will need to have a file outside of test and data, which will access test to run the tests."?

Answer (score 0):

(One place) Python looks for imported files is in the current working directory. So try executing the file from there:

```sh
$ python test/UT_data_handler.py
```

Comment: Tried, same output

Answer (score 0):

When you run a file directly, the file's folder is the only scope it recognizes.

Let's take your 2 files as an example -
`binary/data_handler` and `test/UT_data_handler.py`

When you run `python data_handler.py` or alternatively `python binary/data_handler.py`, the only scope you will have is your `binary` folder.

What you can do is create a file, let's call it `main.py` which should be located in your main project folder.

```
- data
    - ...
- test
    - ...
- binary
    - ...
- main.py
```

And this file is the one that will import your test from the test module and run it.